# j2me: How to use setCommandListener on a TextField?

Tags: java-me, command, textfield, midp, lcdui

I wanted to make it so that when I select a specific `TextField` in a `Form`, I get a specific list of `Command`s,

for example
TextField: OK, Cancel
TextField2: OK, Back, Help

And I succeeded by using `addCommand()` on each of `TextField`s **but I can't tell it what to happen when when I activate one of these commands** since there is no `setCommandListener` method for them.

It throws a `NullPointerException` when I click it.

I also tried to get the commands from their `Form` but it is receiving only the commands that it contains, not the commands that `TextField`s have.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextField is an `Item` object, and to use commands with it you need  **[ItemCommandListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemCommandListener.html)**:

> A listener type for receiving notification of commands that have been invoked on [Item](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html) objects. An Item can have `Commands` associated with it. When such a command is invoked, the application is notified by having the [commandAction()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemCommandListener.html#commandAction%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Command,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Item%29) method called on the `ItemCommandListener` that had been set on the Item with a call to [setItemCommandListener()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html#setItemCommandListener%28javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemCommandListener%29)...

Most likely reason for `NullPointerException` you mentioned is that you did not set appropriate item command listener (it's null by default, thus when MIDP attempts to invoke command action, there is NPE).

To get what you want, besides creating and adding commands, you need to create item command listener, implement code to handle commands in it, then associate your text field with this listener:

```
myTextField.setItemCommandListener(myItemCommandListener);
```